# How to generate list of make targets automatically by globbing subdirectories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to use a single Makefile to generate targets in hundreds of subdirectories. Each subdirectory is a date/time stamp like this: `20120119_153957`, which matches the following pattern `????????_??????`. There are no other subdirectories that match this pattern.

One target I would like to generate is called `????????_??????/graph.pdf`. I have a script called `make_graph` that will make the graph given the subdirectory name. But I'm not sure how to write a Makefile that will automatically glob all of the subdirectores and generate these targets programmatically.

For example, the code `SUBDIRS:=????????_??????` seems to correctly glob all of the subdirectories. I can check with this rule:

```
.PHONY: print
print:
        echo $(SUBDIRS)
```

However this variable assignment

```
TARGETS:=$(SUBDIRS:%=%/graph.pdf)
```

does not seem to do what I expect and assign lots and lots of targets. Instead the following rule just prints one target.

```
.PHONY: print
print:
        echo $(TARGETS)
```

It is very confusing that `SUBDIRS` should have the correct subdirectories but `TARGET` only has one file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your example glob matching is performed by the shell.

GNU Make has the built-in [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function), which you can use as follows:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard ????????_??????)
```

Now you can use this variable to construct a list of targets:

```
.PHONY : all
all : $(SUBDIRS:%=%/graph.pdf)

%/graph.pdf : # list prerequisites here.
    # recipe to make '$@' in directory '$(@D)' from '$^'.
```

See also: [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).