# How to programmatically define targets in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

I am not aware of any way to define programatically targets in GNU Make. How is this possible?

Sometimes one can go away [with alternate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937500/how-to-generate-list-of-make-targets-automatically-by-globbing-subdirectories).  The ability to define programatically targets in Makefiles is however a very important to write and organise complex production rules with `make`. Examples of complex production rules are found in the build system of FreeBSD or in Makefile libraries such as [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl)

The [main differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27293153/2654678) between shell scripts and Makefiles are:

- In a Makefile, the state of the program is given by the command line and the filesystem, so it is possible to resume a job after it has been interrupted. Of course, this requires to properly write the Makefiles, but even if this is rather hard, it is considerably easier than to achieve a similar effect with a shell script.
- In a Makefile, it is ridiculously easy to decorate a procedure with advises or decorate it with hooks, while this is essentially impossible in shell scripts.

For instance, a very simple and useful pattern is the following:

```
build: pre-build
build: do-build
build: post-build
```

This presents the `build` target as a composite of three targets, one containing the actual instructions `do-build` and two other that are hooks, executed before and after `do-build`.  This pattern is used by many build systems written for BSD Make, which incidentally allows programmatic definition of targets, so that one can write in a batch:

```
.for _target in configure build test install
.if !target(${_target})
${_target}: pre-${_target}
${_target}: do-${_target}
${_target}: post-${_target}
.endif
.endfor
```

The condition introduced by the `.if/.endif` block enables the user to use its own definition of any `${_target}`.

What would be the translation of that snippet for GNU Make?

Comment: It should be noted that in GNU make you **do not** get an in-order guarantee between target prerequisites (though without `-j` I believe it is generally safe to assume you do) so your "hooks" don't necessarily do what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Of course, but this is not directly related to the question and I omitted this to keep things simple. In BSD Make, one says, for instance, `.ORDER: pre-build do-build post-build` to enforce serial processing of the mentioned targets.

Comment: With or without `-j`, make will always walk the prerequisites list in the same order.  It's just that with `-j`, make won't wait for previous (non-dependent) prerequisites to finish before starting new ones (of course this can cause some jobs to run in a different order due to prerequisites not completing).  Without `-j` make _does_ guarantee the in-order build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FWIW here is the make equivalent syntax for

```
.for _target in configure build test install
.if !target(${_target})
${_target}: pre-${_target}
${_target}: do-${_target}
${_target}: post-${_target}
.endif
.endfor
```

Basically, you want *make* to see something like this snippet:

```
build: pre-build
build: do-build
build: post-build
```

and similarly for `configure`, `test` and `install`. This suggests a loop with an `eval` somewhere:

```
define makerule =
  $1: pre-$1
  $1: do-$1
  $1: post-$1
endef

targets := configure build test install

$(foreach _,${targets},$(eval $(call makerule,$_)))
```

(to play with this, change `eval` to `info`). Careful with those closures!

FWIW, here's the expansion of the `foreach`:

- *make* expands the list to be iterated over

  - `${targets}` becomes `configure`, `build`, `test` and `install`
  - We have `$(foreach _,configure build test install,$(eval $(call makerule,$_)))`
- `_` is set to the first value, `configure`.
- *make* expands `$(eval $(call makerule,configure))`
- To evaluate the `eval`, *make* expands `$(call makerule,configure)`

  - It does this by setting `1` to `configure`, and expanding `${makerule}` which produces 3 lines of text:
    `configure: pre-configure`
    `configure: do-configure`
    `configure: post-configure`
- `$(eval)` goes to work, reading this text as *make* syntax
- Note that the expansion of the `$(eval)` is empty! All its work is done as a side effect.
  Wash, lather, rinse, repeat.

**Please note: I have to agree with all the other commenters: your pattern is *bad* make. If your makefile is not `-j` safe, then it is *broken* (missing dependencies).**

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer! As I stated in some other comments, I am well aware of parallelism issues and omitted them from my question because I was only interested in the programmatic aspects. But it's good that beginners read your parallelism banner! :D

Answer (score 3):

First this structure is invalid if you ever want to support parallel builds; if you invoke make with the `-j` option it will run all three prerequisite rules at the same time, because while all of them must be complete before `build`, none of them depend on each other so there's no ordering defined (that is, you don't say that `pre-build` must be complete before `do-build` can run).

Second, GNU make has a number of facilities for [programmatically defining rules](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/).  One thing GNU make does not have, currently, is the ability to search the targets which are already defined, so there's no direct analogy to `.if !target(...)`.

However, you CAN search whether a variable has been defined or not using the `.VARIABLES` variable.  So one workaround would be to define a variable if you want your own target and then have your rule generator check that.